# Are cucumber scenarios stories in a sprint?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, cucumber, bdd, atdd

I am just starting off with Cucumber and BDD/ATDP(Acceptance Test Driven Planning) in a new project, I am not 100% sure of what makes up a story, are the scenarios what I will end up using as my sprint stories? I am guessing this should be the case but not 100% sure if I am right, or is it the case that the feature description as in the example below would be the story?

e.g

feature: Ability to duplicate an invoice record

```
In order to re-use a particular invoice details
As a user
I want to be able to duplicate an existing invoice record
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
An user Story is a {small} functionality which can be tested and 
delivered within a timebox. Scenarios represent different ways of interacting 
with that functionality.  So, an User Story may have multiple scenarios. 
Scenarios are implemented in {re-usable} steps.
```

In your case, the various scenarios could be

```
Feature: Invoice duplication
  ...
  Scenario: Valid invoice
  ...    
  Scenario: Non-existing invoice
  ...    
  Scenario: Already duplicated invoice
  ...    
  Scenario: Expired invoice
  ...
```

The scenarios above verify/test your User Story/Feature i.e. Invoice Duplication.

Scrum Guide => https://www.scrum.org/Portals/0/Documents/Scrum%20Guides/2013/Scrum-Guide.pdf#zoom=100

Comment: Hi Bala thanks for your response, so does it mean that the Feature is the story? in the case of the above it would be "Ability to duplicate an invoice record", trying to verify that a feature is equal to a story in a sprint.

Comment: Check this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1707820/what-is-the-difference-between-a-user-story-and-a-feature-in-agile-terminology

Answer (score 1):

a feature is not exactly a story. BUT a feature is between an epic and a user story to be able to sortly categorize a story. wheras stories describe functionalities features describe a capsuled attribute of one system. features are shorter. it depends on how the process of reqirement engineering is done.  similar to stories also a feature may be uncomplete if seen from different contexts, hence scenarios cover the told AND untold and the not yet seen, allowing us to include it in the requirements.